# Chart.js click event to open a custom tooltip does not work sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm using the click event to open a custom tooltip on a line chart, most part of the time it works fine but sometimes the click on the point does not work.

This is my code:

```
 this.myChart = new Chart(myChartRef, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: label,
            datasets: dados,
        },
        options: {               
            elements: {
                line: {
                    fill: false,
                    tension: 0
                },                   
            },
            events: ["click"],                
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true,
                position: 'custom',
                enabled: false,
                animationDuration: 0,
                custom: this.myChartTooltip()
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'x'
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`tooltips.mode: 'nearest'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#nearest), the Chart.js documentations states:

> If `intersect` is true, this is only triggered when the mouse position
>   intersects an item in the graph.

Try to set `intersect: false` or define better suited [interaction `mode`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html) (i.e. [`'x'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#x))